# Flutter StreamBuilder keep updating the widget even when it's not on the screen

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-streambuilder

I'm using `StreamBuilder` to load data from the Firebase Firestore database and keep track of it, and it works fine.

The problem is that I keep receiving updates even when the page is not visible to the user, which could be bad for performance, data usage, and Firebase read cost.

I'm using `MaterialPageRoute` to navigate between pages.

So to transition from the page containing the `StreamBuilder` (page A) to the new page (page B). I'm using this method:

```dart
Navigator.restorablePushNamed(context, "page-b");
```

Page A code:

```dart
class PageA extends StatelessWidget {
  const PageA ({super.key, required this.controller});

  static const routeName = '/page-a';

  final PageAController controller;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Page A'),
      ),
      body: StreamBuilder<String>(
        stream: controller.getLiveDataAsStream(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          log("New Data Received!");
          // Build the UI based on the received data
        }
      },
    ),
  );
}
```

When the user is on page B and new data is received, I can still see the log: 'New Data Received!'

So my question is: Is there any easy way I can stop receiving data from the Stream after leaving Page A until it is visible again?

Comment: Have you tried shifting to a StreamProvider (from riverpod)?  I believe the provider will only trigger a "markNeedsBuild" on the hidden widget, which is a boolean latch, and won't be processed until the next time the widget is visible.

Comment: I want to unsubscribe from the `Stream` to stop receiving updates, thereby avoiding read costs from Firebase Firestore. I don't think `StreamProvider` will help.

Comment: autodispose StreamProvider (or the default generated code for StreamNotifier) does indeed close when not observed.